# Inject an application level Service to @CanActivate

Tags: dependency-injection, angular2-routing

I want to achieve a similar function as Angular1.x routing "resolve" did, by using the @CanActivate routing life-cycle event.

As the trigger for allowing the route to pass, I want to use a service, defined in the application bootstrap (which makes it a single application-wide instance).

`bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    TestObjectModel
])`

The only way I see I can use a dependency within that life-cycle event is by using the following:

`const injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([TestObjectModel]);
const testObjectModel = injector.get(TestObjectModel);`

That indeed gets me an instance of the service, but a new one (not the instance used application-wide).

I tried `Injector.fromResolvedProviders` as well with no better results.

Is there any way I can get my hands on the root Injector inside a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this workaround at: http://embed.plnkr.co/SF8gsYN1SvmUbkosHjqQ/.

It works and allows me to get the single service instance in life-cycle hooks as well.